# Relation between symplectic blow-up of a compact manifold and fibre bundles over same manifold

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, cohomology, fibre-bundles, blow-ups

The symplectic blow-up of a compact symplectic manifold $(X,ω)$ along a compact symplectically embedded submanifold $(M,σ)$ results in another compact manifold $(\tilde{X},\tilde{ω})$ given by
$$\tilde{X}=\overline{X−V}∪φ\tilde{V}$$
where $V$ is a tubular neighborhood of $M$ that is diffeomorphic via $φ$ to $\tilde{V}$ and lives away from the zero section in the canonical line bundle over the projectivization of the normal bundle of $M$ in $X$. The blow-down map $f:\tilde{X}→X$ restricts to a diffeomorphism in $X−V$, so in general, if my understanding is correct, $\tilde{X}$ may not be realized as a fibre bundle over $X$. Indeed, the cohomology algebra for $\tilde{X}$, as shown by McDuff, is a direct sum of the cohomology for $X$ with a finitely generated module over the cohomology of $M$. The Leray-Hirsch theorem gives a tensor product result for the cohomology of fibre bundles and product spaces.

My question is, is it known what circumstances precipitate the symplectic blow-up $\tilde{X}$ to be at least homotopically equivalent to a fibre bundle over $X$? Or is this nonsense?